# Show Command Prompt Window in GUI

Tags: python, tkinter

I build a GUI for a python program using tkinter. It reads a file and does some amount of processing on it which takes some time. I want to show the command prompt window which runs the python program in the same GUI itself. How can I do it?

Comment: Just make a `Text` widget and insert whatever messages you want to?

Comment: I use the `os` module for type a windows command. For example `os.system("msg * hello")`.

Comment: I did not get it..can you be more specific on how to implement this? @D-00

Comment: If you want that python type a command, type `import os` and then you write `os.system()` and inside the parenthesis the command. That just open the command prompt and type automatically a command. See the `os` documentation here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html **But that don't work for the command `msg`.** If you want to try using `os.system`, try `os.system("ping google.fr -t")` for example.